# Incorrect color selection of regions in the map

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, geospatial

I don't understand why the color of legend's labels does not always correspond to the color in the map in my code:

This is my code (that is the modification of [this code](http://bl.ocks.org/rveciana/29671e257e9e724d2857f726844777b6)). The file `provincias.json` is available [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rveciana/d3-composite-projections/master/test/data/provincias.json):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
.nombre{
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 0.5px
}
.graticule {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #777;
  stroke-width: .5px;
  stroke-opacity: .5;
}
.legendLinear
 {
  font-family: "Lato";
  fill:#c2b59b;
}

.legendTitle {
  font-size: 1em;
}
#tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 70px;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.0em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-radius:5px;
  transition: .2s;
}

</style>
<body>
<div id="container">
  <div id="tooltip">
  </div>
</div>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-legend/1.7.0/d3-legend.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-composite-projections/0.3.5/conicConformalSpain-proj.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 1000,
    height = 900;

var projection = d3.geo.conicConformalSpain()
var graticule = d3.geo.graticule().step([2, 2]);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var svg = d3.select("#container").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);


    svg.append("path")
        .datum(graticule)
        .attr("class", "graticule")
        .attr("d", path);

d3.json("provincias.json", function(error, provincias) {
  d3.json("hdi.json", function(error, hdi) {
  var land = topojson.feature(provincias, provincias.objects.provincias);

  var color = d3.scale.linear()
              .domain([0, 10, 1000, 10000, 100000, 300000])
              .range(["#feebe2","#e5d1ff","#ba93ef", "#8D4CE5","#6100E5","#C94D8C"]); //#feebe2

    svg.selectAll(".nombre")
      .data(land.features)
      .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr("d", path)
      .attr("class","nombre")
      .style("fill",function(d){ return color(hdi[d.properties.nombre]) })
      .on("mouseover", function(d){
        //Show the tooltip
        var x = d3.event.pageX;
        var y = d3.event.pageY - 40;

        d3.select("#tooltip")
          .style("left", x + "px")
          .style("top", y + "px")
          .style("opacity", 1)
          .text(d.properties.nombre + "," + hdi[d.properties.nombre]);
      })
      .on("mouseout", function(){
        //Hide the tooltip
        d3.select("#tooltip")
          .style("opacity", 0);
      });

    svg
      .append("path")
        .style("fill","none")
        .style("stroke","#000")
        .attr("d", projection.getCompositionBorders());

    d3.select("svg").append("g")
      .attr("class", "legendLinear")
      .attr("transform", "translate(100,500)");

    var legendLinear = d3.legend.color()
                .title("...")
                .shapeHeight(20)
                .shapeWidth(90)
                .shapeRadius(10)
                .cells([0, 10, 1000, 10000, 100000, 300000])
                .orient("horizontal")
                .labelFormat(d3.format(".00f"))
                .labelAlign("start")
                .scale(color);

    svg.select(".legendLinear")
      .call(legendLinear);

});
});


</script>
```

The content of `hdi.json` is the following:

```
{"Coruña, A":9, "Alicante":158, "Albacete":3,"Almería":0,"Asturias":13,"Álava":12,"Ávila":0,
"Badajoz":10,"Balears, Illes":331,"Barcelona":250000,"Burgos":5,
"Cantabria":12,"Castellón":316,"Ceuta":9,"Ciudad Real":9,"Cádiz":9,"Cuenca":4,
"Córdoba":11,"Cáceres":2,"Girona":21808,"Jaén":0,
"Granada":9,"Huelva":3,"Huesca":74,
"León":5,"Lleida":9672,"Lugo":3,
"Madrid":507,"Murcia":24,"Málaga":25,"Palencia":2,"Pontevedra":6,
"Navarra":23,"Salamanca":6,"Segovia":4,"Sevilla":16,"Soria":2,
"Santa Cruz de Tenerife":16,"Tarragona":22790,
"Teruel":23,"Toledo":4,"Valladolid":44,
"Valencia":423,"Vizcaya":19,"Zamora":0,"Zaragoza":56,"Guipúzcoa":21,
"Guadalajara":5,"Jaen":2,"Rioja, La": 12, "Palmas, Las": 10,"Ourense":2}
```

The particular problem is that `Tarragona` that has the value `22790` is colored in the same color as `Lleida` that has the value `9672`. However, according to my code, `22790` (`Tarragona`) is smaller than `100000` and bigger than `10000`, so it should be colored in `#6100E5`, but it's colored in `#8D4CE5`. 
But, for example, `9672` (`Lleida`) is smaller than `10000`, so it should be colored in `#8D4CE5` (and it is colored in this color, so it's ok).

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be using a linear scale, by definition it has a **continuous range** and will interpolate between the colors.  What you are describing is a [threshold scale](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Quantitative-Scales.md#threshold-scales).  It has a discrete range mapped to subsets of domain values.  Further, you must call it with a range that's N + 1 of the domain, so, this is what you should be after:

```
var color = d3.scale.threshold()
  .domain([10, 1000, 10000, 100000, 30000])
  .range(["#feebe2","#e5d1ff","#ba93ef", "#8D4CE5","#6100E5","#C94D8C"]);
```

Here's an example creating the legend using a threshold scale and [d3-legend](http://d3-legend-v3.susielu.com/).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-legend/1.7.0/d3-legend.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <svg></svg>
  <script>
    var color = d3.scale.threshold()
      .domain([10, 1000, 10000, 100000, 300000])
      .range(["#feebe2", "#e5d1ff", "#ba93ef", "#8D4CE5", "#6100E5", "#C94D8C"]);

    var svg = d3.select("svg");

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "legendLog")
      .attr("transform", "translate(20,20)");

    var logLegend = d3.legend.color()
      .labels([0, 10, 1000, 10000, 100000, 300000])
      .scale(color);

    svg.select(".legendLog")
      .call(logLegend);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but not the legend's labels have been changed to `NaN to 0
0 to 10
10 to 1000
1000 to 10000
10000 to 100000
100000 to 300000`

Comment: Legend's lables should not be changed. How to fix it?

Comment: Mark's answer is to the point. The actual colors of Lleida and Tarragona are different. Lleida is 8f4fe5, as 9672 is at the 96.35% between 1000 and 10000, just as 8f4fe5 is 96.35% between ba93ef and 8d4ce5. Tarragona is 8741e5 because of similar reason.

Comment: @Dinosaurius, see updated answer for how to fix the labels.

Comment: If you are interested, here I posted another related question (it's about adding the second legend): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41448041/how-to-add-the-second-legend-to-the-map

Answer (score 1):

Actually it works as expected.
The exact colors of Lleida and Tarragona are different, the former being #8f4fe5, the latter #8741e5.

Because of the linear scales you use these colors are calculated as:

((9672-1000) * #8d4ce5 + (10000-9672) * #ba93ef)/(10000-1000) = #8f4fe5

((22790-10000) * #6100e5 + (100000-22790) * #8d4ce5)/(100000-10000) = #8741e5

Intuitively, your problem is that 9672 is much closer to 10000 as to 1000, and 22790 is also much closer to 10000 than to 100000, so even if one of them is below 10000, and the other one above it, they are still closer to it, than to the other ends of the ranges.
As Mark suggested in his answer, probably you do not want to use continuous linear scales.